# Form won't close

Tags: c#, winforms

This is a Button code in C# that checks for the correctness of username and password entered by the user if the info is right the login form (`LoginForm`) should disappear and another form should open (`Smart_Pharmacy`) why doesn't the `LoginForm` disappear when the `Smart_Pharmacy` opens?

```
private void LoginBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Abdullah-PC;Initial Catalog=SmartPharmacyDB;Integrated Security=True");
     SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
     com.Connection = con;
     com.CommandText = "select userpass from usertab where username = @username";
     com.Parameters.Add("@username", usernametxt.Text);
     con.Open();
     string returneduserpass = com.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
     con.Close();
     if (returneduserpass == userpasstxt.Text)
     {
         Smart_Pharmacy f = new Smart_Pharmacy();
         f.Show();
         LoginForm l = new LoginForm();
         l.Close();
     }
     else
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Incorrect username or password !");
     }         
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why doesn't the LoginForm disappear when the Smart_Pharmacy opens ?

You are creating a new instance of the LoginForm and you are trying to close that one. You should try closing the current opened LoginForm.

Change your code to:

```
private void LoginBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Abdullah-PC;Initial Catalog=SmartPharmacyDB;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
    com.Connection = con;
    com.CommandText = "select userpass from usertab where username = @username";
    com.Parameters.Add("@username", usernametxt.Text);
    con.Open();
    string returneduserpass = com.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    con.Close();
    if (returneduserpass == userpasstxt.Text)
    {
        Smart_Pharmacy f = new Smart_Pharmacy();
        f.Show();
        this.Close(); //'this' is the current form(LoginForm)
     }
     else
     {
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect username or password !");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new instance of your form and closing that instance, so it does not impact the form you actually want to close.

Assuming `LoginBTN_Click` is a member of your form class, you should only have to write:

```
if (returneduserpass == userpasstxt.Text)
{
    Smart_Pharmacy f = new Smart_Pharmacy();
    f.Show();
    this.Close();  // or simply 'Close()'.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

it looks like you are instantiating a new LoginForm, and then closing that one immediatly.
try closing the currently active form instead:

```
        if (returneduserpass == userpasstxt.Text)
        {
            Smart_Pharmacy f = new Smart_Pharmacy();
            f.Show();
            this.Close();
        }
```